# Control the URL bar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Is there some function in javascript or React.js to tell if a user tries to access an existing page through the URL bar?

Comment: Hi ! Your needs are not clear for me. Do you want to detect that the user is leaving a page, going into the omnibox ? OR, in case he types something in it, to check if this url is reachable ?

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript:
`window.history`
[How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

In React, use should use React Router along with `useHistory` hook :
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory hook:

```
import {useHistory} from “react-router-dom”
```

Then :

```
const {location} = useHistory()
console.log(location.pathname)
```